# Ошибка при установке mysql севера

Tags: mysql

Ввожу:

```
apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

Выводит:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте откройте терминал и напишите:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.6
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```